# Vector Projection Confusion

Tags: vector, project, projection

If I have a vector (0, 0, 9) and I want to project it onto the vector (0, 0.7, 0.7) shouldn't that give me a vector of (0, 9, 9).

I am using the following formula

```
Vector3.Dot (vector, normal) * normal.magnitude * normal;
```

which is returning (0, 0.45, 0.45). What have I missed, isn't the returned vector z suppose to end at the same z position as the projected vector. Like this

[image]

Comment: Both answers are wrong.  The correct result is (0, 4.5, 4.5).

Answer (score 1):

When you project a vector onto another vector, the result's magnitude is always less than or equal to the magnitude of the original vector.

Given a normalized vector *u*, project *v* onto *u* with the formula:

> proj<sub>u</sub> *v* = 〈*u*, *v*〉*u*

Or, in code,

```
Vector3.Dot(vector, normal) * normal
```

The result of projecting (0, 0, 9) onto (0, √1/2, √1/2) is (0, 4.5, 4.5).

Note that `normal.magnitude` is always 1, unless `normal` is not "normal" (in which case you named your variable wrong); and if it's not normal, you need to *divide* by the squared magnitude, not multiply.

```
Vector3.Dot(vector, direction) * direction
    * (1.0 / direction.magnitude_squared)
```

Comment: So how can I project a vector onto another where both the z values are the same?

Comment: That's not projection.  The diagram you drew has it right, the projected vector is one leg of a right angle, the original vector is the hypotenuse.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I should correct myself... it's not an orthogonal projection.  It may still be a projection.  However... not sure what the exact requirements are.